# Get android device name defined by user over wifi

Tags: android, android-wifi

In my Android app I want to detect all Android device names found in the local wireless network. I am able to scan the network and find the devices IP and full qualified domain name (FQDN) like `android-2120ee3b45******`. I'm doing it like:

```
final InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
if (inetAddress.isReachable(400)) {
    final String host = inetAddress.getHostName();
    final String canHost = inetAddress.getCanonicalHostName();
    final String ip = inetAddress.getAddress();
}
```

With `java.net.InetAddress` I only get the IP and the network name like `android-2120ee3b45******`. But I want the Android device name defined by the user on the device like "**Peters Fire TV**" or "**Mikes Samsung SGS6**". I saw apps like AllConnect or AllCast which can grab such name from Fire TV (which is a android device).

How can I get the Android device name defined by the user over the WIFI network?

Answer (score 1):

add this line,

```
for(i=0;i<WifiP2pDeviceList.size();i++){
    WifiP2pDevice device = WifiP2pDeviceList.get(i);
    String deviceName=device.deviceName;
    String devicestatus=device.status;
    //so on
    }
```

Comment: I was not aware of the class WifiP2pDeviceList nor WifiP2pManager. So I have to implement Wi-Fi Peer-to-Peer? I will have a look into it. Thanks.

Comment: I think This link help you for your query https://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2012/08/31/android-wifi-direct-example/

Comment: That's something different. This only lists active WiFi Direct devices. Nothing to do with regular WiFi devices connected to the LAN.