# How to get user-configured Device Name?

Tags: android

I want to retrieve the Device Name field that the user can set in the `System..About Phone` section of the settings. How can I do this?

This is a field that the user can type any name into e.g. "Richard's Pixel".

---

This is not the same as the device model name as stored in `android.os.Build.MODEL` and related fields.

These are *not duplicates* of this question as they relate to the device model name:

- [How can I get the device name in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579968/how-can-i-get-the-device-name-in-android)
- [Android: Get the device name programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20839301/android-get-the-device-name-programmatically)
- [Get Android Device Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071281/get-android-device-name)

This is not a duplicate as it relates to WIFI name:

- [Get android device name defined by user over wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33296712/get-android-device-name-defined-by-user-over-wifi)

---

This is not a duplicate as 1) some solutions return `null`, and 2) some solutions return the Bluetooth name configured in a different part of the settings (i.e. this is a different name):

- [How do you get the user defined "Device Name" in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704597/how-do-you-get-the-user-defined-device-name-in-android)

The solutions that return `null` could just be out of date.

This link is updated and uses similar code, but it works on Android P. This is a duplicate of that post:

- [Android : Get "device name" on android tv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452942/android-get-device-name-on-android-tv)

Comment: Ohhkk .. Need some digging i guess then..

Comment: public String getLocalBluetoothName(){
    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null){
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    }
    String name = mBluetoothAdapter.getName();

I have tested this code in OnePlus 3T with Android 8.0 and it has worked. It returns the device name as set in the about phone.

Comment: What a coincidence . I was just about to post it as an answer xd. `Settings.Global.getString(getContentResolver(), "device_name")` .. Also i don't think all devices have this setting so it can return `null`.

Comment: But I have tested it. I changed the device name in About phone and it also reflects in the bluetooth device name. And vice-versa. I just now tested it in OnePlus 3T with Android 8.0.

Comment: @Pronoy Then it could be device specific - those are 2 very separate fields on the Pixel, which can be configured with very different values.